# Swift - View Hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to bring a view in front of another. the view is hidden and will be displayed upon tapping on a button. This is the Hierarchy i have:

[image]

The view which i need to bring in front is the info View

i have tried to do so:

```
infoView.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: infoView)
```

but it didn't work
i've tried with the z index

```
infoView.layer.zPosition = 100
```

but didn't work either...

Any idea?

Update:
here's the code of the button which is working:

```
@IBOutlet var infoButtons: [UIButton]!

@IBAction func infoButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {if sender.tag == 8 {
        if constraint.count > 0 {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(constraint)
            constraint.removeAll()
        }
        let alignYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: infoButtons[7], attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([alignYConstraint])
        constraint.append(alignYConstraint)
        self.infoView.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
        infoView.isHidden = false
infoView.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: infoView)
}
```

UPDATE:

I have a nib file which is added to the infiView
here's the code for the Xib:

```
import UIKit
class InfoView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

var onClickCallback: (() -> Void)?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("InfoView", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

}
  @IBAction func closeInfoViewPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    onClickCallback?()
  }
}
```

In the other VC i add a view and assign it the class InfoView.
infoView is hidden and on click becomes visibile.
I'm trying to bring it on front of the header when is displayed (which is not a nav controller but a custom view). See picture:

[image: the nib File]

[image: the view when is showed]

[image: the view if i scroll down]

Comment: Offhand, it *looks* like your `bringSubview(toFront:)` should work. Are you sure that line of code is getting processed? I'm assuming you have checked that your `UIButton` IBAction correctly working.

Comment: @dfd yeah i'm sure the button is performing other actions too which are correctly performed....

Comment: If you look at the properties of infoView after you do bringsubview to front, what the frame and bounds and visibility?

Comment: Thanks for posting more code. Instinctively, I don't like the looks of all this constraint code you have. Personally, I avoid removing constraints at all times. Between that code and the `scrollRangeToVisible` call, I'm wondering if your need to break things down. Maybe your `bringSubview(toFront:)` **is** working, but the constraints are making it look like it isn't.

Comment: @dfd that constraint you see it's needed just to update the vertical align with the different button. Is an Infoview which open and depending on which button i click it aligns itself vertically with the specific button. that scrollRangeToVisible is applied to a textView which is inside a UIImageView which is inside a Xib view... it's a bit complex i know... i will update the code to let you this better...

Comment: @solenoid if i print the view before and after i get the same frame not sure how to see the bounds.. here the result: before: .InfoView: 0x7ffa8b65f8c0; frame = (129 -75; 181 115); hidden = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000042c960>>); after: .InfoView: 0x7ffa8b65f8c0; frame = (129 -75; 181 115); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000042c960>>)

Answer (score 0):

Do a right click on your UIButton in the hierarchy from storyboard to find out if your button has a solid connection. A lot of the time this is the case when people get stuck. You may have to reconnect the button from storyboard to code. You shouldn't have to change the z-index for this. the first line of code should work, depending on where you placed the code in your file..

Comment: the infoView view is inside a scroll View... and i'm trying to bring it in front of a view which is out of the scrolling... is it possibile that this is the problem?